# How to tweak in mail Body using MailR in R

Tags: python, r, dplyr, tidyr, sendmailr

I am new to using Library mailR and search a lot on google but couldn't found anything useful.

I have 2 html table in R, i want to sent them using MailR library in mail body but when i'm sending the mail both table looks like joined to each other.

How to tweak mail body using MailR library.

I want mail Looks like below mentioned format.

```
Hi Team,
"some sentence here" using t.start and nrows() in the sentence
```

[image]

space

[image]

```
"some sentence here:
```

I am using the code to make table something like this:

```
Table1<-DF%>% tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
                      widths = rep(100, 13),
                      second_headers = list(c(1, 6, 6),
                                            c("", "ABC", "XYX")),
                      caption = "ABC Stat") %>%
  add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border"),
                             c("bold", "1px solid black")))%>% add_css_row(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue")), rows = 0:2)%>%add_css_caption(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue")))
```

and same code for table2

And to send e-mail the code looks like:

```
library(mailR)
sender<-"a12db@gmail.com"


recipients<-c("xyc@gmail.com")

sm<-list(host.name = "smmm.gmail.com", port = 123,
         user.name="a12db@gmail.com",
         passwd="1#4$12#", ssl=TRUE)

send.mail(from=sender,
          to=recipients,
          subject = paste0("Abc Repo"),
          body = paste("Some sentence",Table1,"\br",Table2),
          html = TRUE,
          inline = FALSE,
          smtp = sm,
          authenticate = TRUE,
          attach.files =("abc.csv") ,
          send = TRUE )
```

Comment: Very unclear what you want. Show the data you are working with, and what the desired outcome is. Right now, it's super unclear what the outcome is.

Comment: @leeum Updated the question.

Comment: Can you add the code you're using and reproducible form of your tables which you want to send through an email?

Comment: @suchait Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
paragraphs <- list(
  glue::glue("Some sentence with {nrow(iris)}:"),
  tab1 = iris[1:3,1:3],
  tab2 = iris[1:3,3:5],
  glue::glue("And another sentence")
)
html <- do.call(paste, c(lapply(paragraphs, knitr::kable, format = "html"), list(sep="<br>")))
smtp <- list(
  host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", 
  port = 465, 
  user.name = "....", 
  passwd = "...", 
  ssl = TRUE
)
from <- to <- "....."
library(mailR)
send.mail(from = from,
          to = to,
          subject = "Report",
          html = TRUE,
          body = html,
          smtp = smtp,
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: @Roy1245 I am sry.

Comment: @IukeA it's okay.

Comment: I have already converted both the table in `htmltable` format, can you help me with that how to paste it in mail body with one space distance.

Comment: @Roy1245 `paste("Some sentence",Table1,Table2,sep="<br>")`?

Comment: @Roy1245 Please edit your question and provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250) as asked by the R tag (hover over it). Otherwise everything will be guess work. You code is missing `DF`, the required packages etc.

Comment: Required Package is `mailR` as I have mentioned in question and DF same as `Table1`.

Comment: @Roy1245 Again, please *READ* the information behind the link I provided, and feel free to come back with a proper example.